# Debug run with AndroidTestOrchestrator stuck waiting for debugger

Tags: android-studio, android-testing

When running an Espresso test with Android Test Orchestrator enabled the test runs fine without Debugger but when starting test with Debugger the test just hangs with the following logcat message:

`I/AndroidTestOrchestrator: Waiting for debugger to connect...`

The test also runs fine with Debugger attached if I disable Android Test Orchestrator.

Any ideas how to get this working or if this is a known issue?

#### Environment

- Android Studio 3.1.3
- Support Test Library version: 1.0.2
- Target SDK: 27
- Device under Test: Emulator API 27

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is a bug in Support Test Library 1.0.2 per https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/78658117.

I was able to workaround the issue by downgrading to 1.0.1 but also reset my emulator data before being able to Debug with Orchestrator.